# MySQL Error Code 3813: "Column Check Constraint", can't create table

Tags: mysql, database

I am attempting to create my first database in MySQL and running into a bit of a problem, when attepting to run the following table, I am getting the following error:

> Error Code 3813: Column check constraint 'section_ck_1' references other column.

Here is the table I am trying to write

```
create table section (
course_id varchar(8),
sec_id varchar(8),
semester varchar(6) check (semester in (`Fall`, `Winter`, `Spring`, `Summer`)),
year numeric(4,0) check (year > 1701 and year < 2100),
building varchar(15),
room_number varchar(7),
time_slot_id varchar(4),
primary key (course_id, sec_id, semester, year),
foreign key(course_id) references course(course_id) on delete cascade,
foreign key (building, room_number) references classroom on delete set null);
```

I believe it is something incorrect with my 'semester' or 'year' rows, although I am not sure what the problem is, or how I would go about fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
semester varchar(6) check (semester in (`Fall`, `Winter`, `Spring`, `Summer`)),
```

I think you meant to use single-quotes to make the four seasons string literals. It should be like this:

```
semester varchar(6) check (semester in ('Fall', 'Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer')),
```

String literals belong in single-quotes.

Back-quotes are for delimiting identifiers, like table names and column names. Using the back-quotes the way you did made it seem like you intended `semester` to have the same value as one of four other columns, named `Fall`, `Winter`, `Spring`, `Summer`.